# asp.net Gridview with objects

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

Hey guys i need some help with my GridView, i just started this asp.net thing and i´m not sure if this is even possible.

so here is my Problem:

I have a GridView with "DateTime" Objects.

```
            DataTable Timetable = new DataTable();

            Timetable.Columns.Add("From", typeof(DateTime));
            Timetable.Columns.Add("To", typeof(DateTime));

            DataRow dr = Timetable.NewRow();

            dr[0] = Convert.ToDateTime(TextBox_TFrom.Text);
            dr[1] = Convert.ToDateTime(TextBox_TTo.Text);

            Timetable.Rows.Add(dr);

            trainingTimes.DataSource = Timetable;
            trainingTimes.DataBind();
```

This is how i add my first row and until this Point, it works fine. 
So what i did on my other Gridviews is to get always the current data, if the page is loaded.

```
    public DataTable currentTimeGridView()
    {


        DataTable table = new DataTable();

        foreach (TableCell cell in trainingTimes.HeaderRow.Cells)
        {


            table.Columns.Add(cell.Text);

        }

        foreach (GridViewRow row in trainingTimes.Rows)
        {

            table.Rows.Add();

            for (int i = 0; i < row.Cells.Count; i++)
            {

                Label4.Text = trainingTimes.Columns.ToString();

                table.Rows[row.RowIndex][i] = row.Cells[i];

            }


        }


        return table;


    }
```

But now i cant get my DateTime Object back from the GridView, is there anyway i can get it? this stuff worked with strings, but now i cant find the answer how to get my Object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of this

```
  table.Rows[row.RowIndex][i] = row.Cells[i]
```

Use Below code

```
table.Rows[row.RowIndex][i] = row.Cells[i].Text;
```

Comment: Wow, i dont know why, but it works now! i used this yesterday and i did not work.. suddenly it does... mindblow^^